# intersection theory on projective space

Tags: algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory

Let $\mathcal{L} := O(1) \in Pic(\mathbb{P}^d)$ be considered as an element of $CH^1(\mathbb{P}^d)$. What is its $d$-fold power in $CH^d(\mathbb{P}^d) = \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Do you know what a generator of $CH^d$ looks like geometrically? Now intersect $d$ general hyperplanes, and compare.

Comment: I would guess that it is just a single closed point. So $[\mathcal{L}]^d = 1 \in CH^d(\mathbb{P}^d)$?

Comment: Dear user5262: Right!